# how to trigger MySQL query when DATETIME is past

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

**Good evening,**

I have 1 table where i store a element with the type : datetime,
I am going to insert a date into this element by a script on php.

When the date is reached i want to increase "datepast" from table2,
we can do it by comparing "name" from table1 with "person_name" from table2.

Now the question is how to trigger a sql script to do this job for me, it would be great if it was real time.

Already thanks,

create table if not exists table1 (
    name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    finishtime DATETIME,
    id_table1 int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 primary key ( id_table1 ));

create table if not exists table2 (
    person_name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    datepast int,
    id_table1 int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 primary key ( id_table1 ));

Comment: Either post your solution or delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cronjobs and MySQL events can do a good job handling such things. But the queries you put in there must be set up to be idempotent -- that is, they must be set up so if you run them more than once they have the same effect as running them once. Otherwise you will have a brittle solution.

When you're handling data based on expiration times like your `finishtime`, it's usually a good idea to try to use a query or a view, rather than an update.

For example you could create this view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table2 AS
 SELECT name      AS person_name
        COUNT(*)  AS datepast
   FROM table1
  WHERE datepast <= NOW()
  GROUP BY name
```

Then, `SELECT * FROM table2` will generate a result set just like `SELECT person_name, datepast FROM table2` might generate. But the SELECT resultset will always be precisely accurate in time.

**Wait!** you say, *isn't that inefficient?*  The answer is, probably not unless you have several hundred thousand rows or more in your `table`. SQL is built for this kind of declarative data stuff.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it tomorow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL events or a Cronjob. It is not real-time, but it can be close to.

Because your posting is not complete and table2 is missing, I can only give you an example how to setup an event. Inside `DO BEGIN and END $$` you can add your MySQL query to update datepast.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
EVENT `increase_date_past` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND
DO BEGIN
{{READ DATE AND UPDATE TABLE2}}
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Events are not activated by default, you have to go to

```
In /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and activate events by placing a line inside `[mysqld]` tag.

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=1
```

and then `sudo service mysql restart`